# How to parse the date string in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: javascript

I have date string in the format '2020/02/25 23:58:08' . I want to parse it to '2020-02-25".

Note : Initially date is in string format, after conversion whether it is in date or string format it doesn't matter.

**file.js**

```
   function test (filepath) {

    let date = "2020/02/25 23:58:08";
    date = date.replace("//"/gi,"-");
   // I am not familiar with regular expressions, I want to omit the data related to hours, seconds extra   
   }
```

When I ran the program, I gotUncaught ReferenceError: gi is not defined, gi is to globally replace

Comment: `new Date('2020/02/25 23:58:08').toISOString().slice(0, 10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
let date = "2020/02/25 23:58:08";
var date2 = new Date(date)
console.log(date2.toISOString().slice(0,10))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let date = `2020/02/25 23:58:08`;
let parsedDate = date.split(" ")[0].replace(/\//gi,'-');
console.log(parsedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the line using regex, should be:

```
let date = "2020/02/25 23:58:08";
date = date.replace(/\//gi,"-");
```

Then to get only the date, you can get the first 10 characters:

```
date.slice(0,10)
```

Final code:

```
let date = "2020/02/25 23:58:08";
date = date.replace(/\//gi,"-");
date.slice(0,10)
```

Although there are other ways to do it, you can use a library like momentJs which includes methods for this, like moment.format, it gives so many possibilities. But if you have a small case this is fine.